# Cannot run android app in background through service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I try to get current location when the app running in background, so I use service. However, the data does not change in background, the service does not work. I want to know the problem. Here is the code of the app.

MainActivity as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn_start;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
boolean boolean_permission;
TextView tv_latitude, tv_longitude, tv_address,tv_area,tv_locality;
SharedPreferences mPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor medit;
Double latitude,longitude;
Geocoder geocoder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    tv_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    tv_latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
    tv_longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
    tv_area = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_area);
    tv_locality = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_locality);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    medit = mPref.edit();


    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (boolean_permission) {

                if (mPref.getString("service", "").matches("")) {
                    medit.putString("service", "service").commit();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
                    startService(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable the gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    fn_permission();
}

private void fn_permission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) {


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

                    },
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

        }
    } else {
        boolean_permission = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                boolean_permission = true;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        latitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latitude"));
        longitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longitude"));

        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

            tv_area.setText(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
            tv_locality.setText(stateName);
            tv_address.setText(countryName);



        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        tv_latitude.setText(latitude+"");
        tv_longitude.setText(longitude+"");
        tv_address.getText();


    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}


}
```

Service as follow:

```
public class GoogleService extends Service implements LocationListener{

boolean isGPSEnable = false;
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
double latitude,longitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;
long notify_interval = 1000;
 public static String str_receiver = 
"com.findmyelderly.findmyelderly.receiver";
Intent intent;




public GoogleService() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(),5,notify_interval);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
//        fn_getlocation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private void fn_getlocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {

    } else {

        if (isNetworkEnable) {
            location = null;
            try {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {

                        Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                        Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


            if (isGPSEnable) {
                location = null;
                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                            Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            fn_update(location);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

    }

    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fn_getlocation();
                }
            });

        }
    }


private void fn_update(Location location){

    intent.putExtra("latutide",location.getLatitude()+"");
    intent.putExtra("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


}
```

build.gradle as follow

```
.........
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

AndroidManifest as follow

```
..........

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

.........

<service android:name=".GoogleService" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am very puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to check the permissions of the app on the phone itself. I've found with my device (Android version 6.0.1) it's not enough to just add "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> and
    "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />"
in the manifest, you have to grant permissions to the app manually on the device.

To do this, go to Settings > Apps > 'yourApp' > Permissions and slide across the bar to turn on Location for that app.

I'm new enough to Android apps myself so there may be a bigger problem in your case I'm not sure but worth a try anyway!